# ngSubmit not getting submitted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, forms

I am pretty much beginner with AngularJS, and I am trying to submit a form, as follows:

```
<div ng-include="APP_URL + '/view/myResolver/searchForm.html'" ng-controller="MySearchFormController">   </div>
```

This is my searchForm.html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-14">
        <div class="well">
          <div class="col-md-9">
                <form ng-submit="submit()" class="form-horizontal clearfix" role="form" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="teamName" class="col-md-3 control-label">Team name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="myName" id="myName" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
           </div>
<div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-0"></div>
                     <button ng-click="onFormReset()" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                     <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search"/>
</div>
                </form>

            {{teamName}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('MySearchFormController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.submit = function (){

      if ($scope.myName) {
        alert($scope.myName);
        $scope.teamName = this.teamName;
      }
    }
  }]);
```

What is currently happening is the text is automatically appearing in the {{teamName}} field.
Instead, I would like to make it work only onSubmit(), namely clicking the Search button.

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: I have just edited it.

Comment: actually `this.teamName` refers to the scope of the `$scope.submit` method. I think you want to do `$scope.teamName = $scope.myName;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this :

```js
function demo ($scope) {
  
  $scope.submit = function () {
    $scope.submitted = true;
  };
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="demo">

  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="teamName">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  
  <p ng-if="submitted">{{ teamName }}</p>
  
</div>
```

**BUT** it is not optimal, as once you submitted one time, `$scope.submitted` is `true` and you will get the same problem, again.

**SO**, I would recommend you to not bind your `{{ teamName }}` to the same reference as the input :

```js
function demo ($scope) {
  
  $scope.submit = function () {
    
    $scope.teamNameCopy = angular.copy($scope.teamName);
    
  };
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="demo">
  
  <form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="teamName">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  
  <p>{{ teamNameCopy }}</p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it, meriadec.

Your snippet contains exactly what I am trying to do, but there is possibly another issue in my code, as again it is not running.

Btw, how can I edit the topic's subject? It should be *not* instead of *now*.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the issue is resolved.

Unfortunately, that was an issue related to incorrectly closing html tags, and not